# Changing SQL Server DB from tabular to multidimensional

Tags: sql-server, multidimensional-array, ssas, sql-server-2014, tabular

I have following problem: When I try to deploy my SSAS project (with cube, dimensions and all that jazz) to sql-server, it throws error saying that

> You cannot deploy the model because the DB deployment server is not running in multidimensional mode.

I'm new to this, so it might be a dumb question, but how do I change database mode from tabular to multidimensional?

Comment: I think you mean SSAS, and not SSIS.

Comment: This is highly probable, as I've written, I'm really new to this. Going to edit tag.

Comment: Are you trying to change the mode of the server or change the mode of your project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tabular and Multi Dimensional are completely different thing.
When you install SQL Server, you have to choose which one you are going to install.

So, if you create a Tabular model, you only can deploy it to Tabular installation of SSAS and the same for Multi Dimensional

you can not convert those model to each other.

Comment: While it is recommended you reinstall I will post a way to do this as an alternate answer.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to stop SSAS, edit the msmdsrv.ini and change DeploymentMode from 2 to 0. Empty the DataDir folder. Then start SSAS. This will change the instance from Tabular mode to Multidimensional mode. It will not convert models.

Cathy Dumas describes the reverse [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140110091629/http://cathydumas.com/2012/04/23/changing-an-analysis-services-instance-to-tabular-mode/).

Comment: Good to know, but the model still will not convert. Generally, it is better to install another instance of SSAS to have both tabulat and MUD. It is pretty like installing 2 instance of SQL Server in one machine.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I answered the question. OP has a tabular model and looks like he was trying to deploy that to Multi Dimensional server.

Answer (score 11):

Best recommendation is to reinstall *only* **SQL Server Analysis Services** feature without disrupting other features/components like SQL Server Engine. During reinstallation of the feature, we can change the configuration of **Analysis Services** to **Multidimensional and Data Mining Mode**. The whole reinstall process takes less than 10 minutes. So, this approach is easy and quick.

I'm enlisting all the steps here for SQL Server 2017 installation:

1. Go to Add Remove Program (ARP) Window in Control Panel. Alternatively, you run **appwiz.cpl** command from Windows **Run** prompt (Refer screenshot).

   [image]

   Select the row for **Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (64-bit)** and click on <kbd>Uninstall/Change</kbd> (Refer screenshot).

   [image]
2. It'll open the SQL Server 2017 change wizard (Refer screenshot):

   [image]
3. Click on <kbd>Remove</kbd> link
4. Select the **Analysis Services** checkbox on **Select Features** step of uninstallation wizard (Refer screenshot):

   [image]
5. Complete remove action by following the remaining steps in the guided wizard. They are self-explanatory in nature.
6. Restart from step 1 but this time click on <kbd>Add</kbd> link (Refer screenshot in step # 2) to start installation wizard.
7. During feature addition, it'll ask for the location of SQL Server setup files. Setup files can be present in a folder in your hard disk, Compact Disk (CD), or a mounted virtual drive via an ISO image file.
8. Reinstall **SQL Server Analysis Services** feature. On the **Analysis Services Configuration** step of the installation wizard, go to **Server Configuration** tab and select the **Multi-dimensional and Data Mining Mode** option button (Refer screenshot):

   [image]
9. Click <kbd>Next ></kbd> and complete the installation by following the remaining steps in the guided wizard. They are self-explanatory in nature.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do it go edit the MSMDSRV.ini and change the deployment mode to either (0,1,2,3) depending on what you are trying to use. Also remember that you have to log off the SQL studio and log back in.