# SQL Server 2017 multidimensional mode needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

MS SQL Server 2017 (developer edition) is connected and running on my PC. However, when I want to `start` the `develop` process in MS Visual studio 2017, it is giving me the following error:

```
You cannot deploy the model because the localhost deployment server is not running in multidimensional mode.
```

I tried reinstalling MS SQL server with additional features, but I cannot find this `multidimensional option`. I googled some articles and they solved it in older versions of MS VS, however, they are not helpful in MS VS 2017. Please, give some suggestions.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what is this "develop" process you are trying to start is?

Comment: I am trying to build an OLAP cube.

Comment: any ideas? @BradleyUffner

Comment: That mode is selected at installation time of the instance and can't be changed as far as I know. You will need to reinstall analysis services with that option, or add a new instance with it selected.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36483966/1747983

Comment: If one has more than one local instance then the default will be chosen. One can Right click the project and correct the instance to the correct one. My default instance does not have multidimensional so I changed the connection string and this solved this issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, it turns out I did not need to re-install the instance. Instead, I had to change `msmdsrv.ini` in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config`. The line `<DeploymentMode>2</DeploymentMode>` in the file (`2` means tabular) should be changed to `<DeploymentMode>0</DeploymentMode>`. After restarting the analysis server, I finally managed to run the server in `multidimensional mode`.

Comment: Nice one bro. Just a word to the wise: close your SQL manager first and open this ini file in admin mode.

Comment: Microsoft suggests not to change DeploymentMode manually. The better solution would be to reinstall Analysis services and choosing Multidimensional mode during the installation. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/determine-the-server-mode-of-an-analysis-services-instance?view=asallproducts-allversions